# jQuery closest() not working on next element in hierarchy

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html structure:

```
<em class="help fa fa-question-circle text-muted"></em>
<div class="help-wrapper"></div>
```

And when using the following JS I assumed it would be fine but it doesn't work. No errors or anything, just won't work.

```
$('.help').on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest('.help-wrapper').fadeToggle(300);
});
```

Comment: The document is very clear. Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `next` or `siblings` in the context

```
$('.help').on('click', function () {
  $(this).next('.help-wrapper').fadeToggle(300);
});
```

or

```
 $('.help').on('click', function () {
  $(this).siblings('.help-wrapper').fadeToggle(300);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`closest()` traverses **up** the DOM tree, so any matches are ancestors of `this`.

You need `next()`:

```
$(this).next('.help-wrapper').fadeToggle(300);
```

Answer (score 2):

Closes traverses the tree up, it does not work on `siblings`
In your case you can use

```
$(this).siblings('.help-wrapper').fadeToggle(300);
```